# Can't seem to render HTML in my AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Forgive a total AngularJS newbie.

I'm having trouble rendering HTML content in my Angular app!

Given the following partial:

```
<div ng-app="myGreatApp" ng-repeat="article in articles" >
    <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="article.full"></div>
    {{article.full}}
</div>
```

The HTML is rendered in escaped fashion using the `{{article.full}}` but the div is always empty.

Not getting any JS errors in the console.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: tried it with and without the `ng-app="myGreatApp"` but that didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ng-bind-html`. I believe `ng-bind-html-unsafe` was removed [some time ago](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dae694739b9581bea5dbc53522ec00d87b26ae55).

Answer (score 1):

may be you need to add [ngSanitize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It's working now with the ngSanitize.